# BaasBox and C# from WP8?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, baasbox

I'm doing some test from my WP8 device and try to connect a native app to the BaasBox service.  Since BaasBox doesn't have support for WP yet, i'm trying to establish a connection following the supported JavaScript documentation

The C# code using the `HttpClient` class:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    //Send HTTP request
    //This code sets the base URI for HTTP requests, 
    //and sets the Accept header to "application/json", which tells the server to send data in JSON format
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://openerp.homelinux.com:9000");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    //
    BaasBoxLogin login = new BaasBoxLogin();
    login.userName = "testuser";
    login.password = "testpwd";
    login.appcode = "1234567890";

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(new Uri("http://openerp.homelinux.com:9000/console/"), login);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //get the uri of the created resource
        Uri gizmoResponse = response.Headers.Location;
    }
    else
    {
        this.LblToken.Text = "TokenId: NOT Found";
    }
}
```

When running and debugging the above code from my device the following messages is generated after trying to establish the connection:

```
{
    StatusCode: 404,
    ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found',
    Version: 0.0,
    Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent,
    Headers: {
            Content-Length: 399 Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    }
}
```

As mentioned before, I'm using the `HttpClient` class. However, i'm considering to use the `HttpWebRequest` to achieve log in to the BaasBox service

Any idea how to perform this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided by @eliantor is correct but the endpoint is wrong. The right one is `http://openerp.homelinux.com:9000/login` without the last `/`.

Answer (score 2):

The endpoint you are connecting to is wrong.

Provided the specific user has been created on the server.

You should make a post to: `http://openerp.homelinux.com:9000/login/`
And provide a custom header `X-BAASBOX-APPCODE: 1234567890`

Also, currently, you should provide the body for the login request as:
**application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

In general you can follow the examples provided for the rest api in curl:
http://www.baasbox.com/documentation/?shell#login

Comment: Thanks you for your help eliantor. I've already try your solution and now I can get a valid response from the BaasBox server. The problem I'm facing now is how to get the X-BB-SESSION value from the Header section