# Creating a document in BaasBox using HttpClient?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, httpclient, baasbox

Following with this BaasBox series, I previously posted [BaasBox and C# from WP8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25092478/baasbox-and-c-sharp-from-wp8)
to know how to perform a log in from a WP8 App to a BaasBox server. I have accomplished that.

Now, I am facing a problem when trying to create a new record (In BaasBox it's called Document. See [here](http://www.baasbox.com/documentation/?shell#create-a-document)) into an specific collection.

This is the code I'm using:

```
string sFirstName = this.txtFirstName.Text;
string sLastName = this.txtLasttName.Text;
string sAge = this.txtAge.Text;
string sGender = ((bool)this.rbtnMale.IsChecked) ? "Male" : "Female";

try
{
    using(var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        //Step 1: Set up the HttpClient settings
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://MyServerDirecction:9000/document/MyCollectionName");
        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        //Step 2: Create the request to send
        HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://MyServerDirecction:9000/document/MyCollectionName");
        //Add custom header
        requestMessage.Headers.Add("X-BB-SESSION", tokenId);

        //Step 3: Create the content body to send
        string sContent = string.Format("fname={0}&lname={1}&age={2}&gender={3}", sFirstName, sLastName, sAge, sGender);
        HttpContent body = new StringContent(sContent);
        body.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        requestMessage.Content = body;

        //Step 4: Get the response of the request we sent
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
             //Code here for success response
        }
        else
             MessageBox.Show(response.ReasonPhrase + ". " + response.RequestMessage);
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

When testing the code above I got the following exceptionÑ

```
{Method: POST, RequestUri: 'http://MyServerDirecction:9000/document/MyCollectionName', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
  X-BB-SESSION: e713d1ba-fcaf-4249-9460-169d1f124cbf
  Content-Type: application/json
  Content-Length: 50
}}
```

Does anyone know how could I send an json data using HttpClient to a BaasBox Server? Or what is wrong with the code above?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send the body in the JSON format.
According to the BaasBox documentation, the body payload must be a valid JSON (http://www.baasbox.com/documentation/?shell#create-a-document)

Try to format the sContent string as:

```
//Step 3: Create the content body to send
string sContent = string.Format("{\"fname\":\"{0}\",\"lname\":\"{1}\",\"age\":\"{2}\",\"gender\":\"{3}\"}", sFirstName, sLastName, sAge, sGender);
```

Or you can use JSON.NET (http://james.newtonking.com/json) or any other similar library to manipulate JSON stuff in a simple way.

Comment: Hi Giastfader. Thaks for your help. However, not sure that the problem is the JSON format (I used the same approach I posted when implemented the login and it worked). I try your suggestion and it throws an exception that the string is not in the correct format. My guess is that it seems that it's related with the place where the content of the sContent is added. I mean either in the header or in the body.

Comment: Hi again. After all, seems your suggestion was OK. Doing some testing I found that one of the problems I was getting the error was the string format was not correct. I use the following line of code: string sContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(personData); The other thing that was causing the problem was a data inside that string that I didn't set up properly. fixing both issues, now I'm able to add a new record.